# The right phrase for "stand with the name" for a product?

Tags: phrases, expressions, translation

There is a well known german phrase:

> Dafür stehe ich mit meinem Namen

Which indicates, that a person or company promises quality of his/their product. And to underline it, they guarentee this with the good name.
It's tough to explain, but I hope you get it.

Now I would like to know a phrase in English language, which is likely to be known and has this meaning.

The direct translation doesn't sound right to me:

> This is what I stand for with my name.

Comment: The closest English set phrase I can think of is something like "I pledge on my honour" - but that's VERY archaic. Or "You have our word" - but I think the modern English-speaking world is probably too cynical to trust this kind of promise. Most equivalent ads make reference to a concrete promise with legal status, like a money-back guarantee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd render this with something like:

> I vouch for it with my reputation

or

> I stand behind my {product / service}

or

> I put my name to my {product / service} with pride

or

> I {stake my reputation / pride myself} on the quality of my {product / service}.

Answer (score 1):

Our name *is* the guarantee ; an [example](http://www.yellowpages.com/ewing-nj/mip/e-f-super-clean-llc-our-name-is-the-warranty-451870357).